# Select two columns one join

Tags: sql, oracle11g, left-join

Given this SQL query:

```
select A.field1 as field
from A left join B
on A.field1 = B.field1 
union all
select A.field2 as field 
from A left join B
on A.field2 = B.field1;
```

Is there some way to get the same with few lines? i.e: is there another way to get two columns from a table A joined each one separated with a column from the table B, and then both put into the same resultset column?
The reason for needing that is the real query has a more complex join and where conditions, and for that is a bit big and, almost all, redundant.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This query is strange. It is nearly identical to "select field1 from A union all select field2 from A" (the difference would be if there are duplicates in table B on field1). What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `left join` and assuming that the join to `B` doesn't produce duplicates, then your query is more simply written as:

```
select A.field1 as field from A
union all
select A.field2 from A;
```

The `left join` to `B` doesn't do anything in this case.

I assume your query is more complicated or you intend an inner join.  You could do the `union all` *before* the `join`:

```
select A.field
from (select field1 from A union all
      select field2 from A
     ) a join
     B
     on A.field = B.field1 ;
```

Whether or not this has worse or the same performance depends on the nature of the data.